# How can I create a switch for class members?

Tags: c++, class, switch-statement

Say I have a class with a couple of data members, and I want a class method that returns one, and the next time it is called returns the value of the other. Something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass():switch(0){};
        int get();
    private:
        int intA, intB;
        int sw;
};        
int MyClass::get()
{ 
    if ( (++sw)%2 )
        return intA;
    else
        return intB;
}
```

What would a more elegant way of doing it be? I don't like the if...else statement very much. It's fine for something like return, but if I'm actually using more complex operations, I end up duplicating a ton of code. Or having to create a second method within each method that is called after I resolve what element I'm pointing to.

What I'd prefer to do, ideally, is to use some form of pointer, so I can do

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass():switch(&intA){};
        int get();
        void toggleSwitch();
    private:
        int intA, intB;
        int * sw;
};        
int MyClass::get()
{
    return *sw;
}
void MyClass::toggleSwitch()
{
    if ( sw == &intA )
        sw = &intB;
    else
        sw = &intA;
}
```

Or something to that effect. I could call toggleSwitch(), and have my class operate on either one or the other value easily.

I still don't like it though. I prefer to avoid if's when possible, and I shouldn't need one in this case. This use of a naked pointer should be pretty safe, but I was thinking I could have something like std::unique_ptr holding each element and then std::swap them. But then the pointers would own the elements, and they'd be dynamic memory instead.

So is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'd make it a `bool`, not use the `switch` keyword, switch by saying `sw = !sw;`, and get it by `return sw ? intA : intB;`.

Comment: @chris Oh, right. The keyword. Oops. While that's ok for a return, it doesn't fix the fact that for other operations it requires duplicating code, or duplicating the number of methods (the initial call to identify on which member I'll work, and then the method that actually does the work).

Comment: What are your requirements? That it automatically toggles, or that it can be toggled?

Comment: @PeterWood It doesn't really matter. What I need is to be able to have the object act on one or the other member under certain circumstances. How it decides which to work on is besides the point. I made it automatic to simplify the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `switch` is a keyword, but I'll roll with it. How about an array of pointers?

```
int *fields[] = {&intA, &intB};

int MyClass::get()
{
    return *fields[++switch % 2];
}
```

This would expand nicely if you could have additional variables later.

Or maybe:

```
int MyClass::get()
{
    return *fields[switch = 1 - switch];
}
```

If you return a *reference* then you could use get() internally.

```
int &MyClass::get()
{
    return *fields[switch = 1 - switch];
}
```

Comment: Fixed the name of the switch variable. This looks like a promising lead. Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking I'll keep the general idea. Though I'll probably go with a struct of references, initialized in the constructor. That should let me keep the [] access and avoid pointer notation (less error prone).

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate the concept of a toggling value:

```
template<typename T>
class Toggleable {
    T first;
    T second;
    T* current;
    T* other;

public:
    Toggleable(const T& first, const T& second)
    : first(first),
      second(second),
      current(&first),
      other(&second) {
    }

    bool toggle() {
        std::swap(current, other);
    }

    const T& get() const {
        return *current;
    }
}
```

Then use as:

```
class MyClass
{
    Toggleable<int> value;

    public:
        MyClass()
        : value(42, 1729)
        {
        }

        const int& get() {
            value.toggle();
            return value.get();
        }
};
```

Comment: This is the same as my original example. It hides the method, but it's still doing an if...else. Which means duplicating code for methods more complex than a single return. I want the program to go straight for the value I need, not to make a series of tests.

Comment: I've fixed to use pointers, swap, and templates so it works with any type.